# Storing input value in Array, getting duplicate console logs

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log

I am trying to store input values from an HTML form using javascript.  I have the result I am looking for but not certain if it is the correct or most efficient way, as each time I press submit, it loops through and increase the array, but also the console log duplicates by one.
I am already quite aware that I have two console logs, that was not the question.  The downvote without explanation is quite unnecessary as how am I to improve my query's?

```js
let inputArr= [];

document.getElementById("submit-btn").onclick = function submitFormVal(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  let inputVal;
  
  inputVal = document.getElementById("form-val").value;
  
  console.log(inputVal);
    
  inputArr.push(inputVal);
  
  for(let i =0; i < inputArr.length;i++){
    inputArr[i];
    inputArr = inputArr.map(Number);
    console.log(inputArr);
  };
};
```

```html
<form id="form-test">
  <input type="number" id="form-val" value="1">
  <button  id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what is this line `inputArr.map(Number);` doing

Comment: @brk converting an array of Strings to an array of Numbers

Comment: why not convert the value to number before pushing. What's that loop doing there

Comment: So your problem is that you have multiple console logs that have the same content? That's because you are using console.log in a for-loop. `console.log(inputArr);` logs the array inputArr.length times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `console.log()` is inside your loop. As the array grows, the loop iterates more and so you get more logging of the same array.

Move it so that it runs after the loop and use `console.clear()` at the beginning of the function so you only see the newest data.

Also, don't use a `submit` button if you aren't actually submitting any data anywhere. Just use a regular button and then you don't need to worry about cancelling the `submit` event.

Lastly, use modern standards. `onclick` (an event property) limits your ability to work with the event. Instead use **[`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**

```js
let inputArr= [];

document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  console.clear(); // clear out old data
  
  let inputVal;
  
  inputVal = document.getElementById("form-val").value;
  
  console.log(inputVal);
    
  inputArr.push(inputVal);
  
  for(let i =0; i < inputArr.length;i++){
    inputArr[i];
    inputArr = inputArr.map(Number);
  };
  console.log(inputArr);
});
```

```html
<form id="form-test">
  <input type="number" id="form-val" value="1">
  <button type="button" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, with all that in mind, the real solution here is much simpler than what you are doing. There is no need for a loop that creates a new array of numbers with one more item in it. All you have to do is **[`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** the new data (with a simple number conversion) into the existing array. Also, get your DOM reference just once before the button is pressed so you don't have to keep finding it every time the button is pushed.

```js
let inputArr= [];

// Get your DOM reference just once, not every time you click the button
let inputVal = document.getElementById("form-val")

document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  console.clear(); // clear out old data
  inputArr.push(+inputVal.value);  // the prepended + implicitly converts the string to a number
  console.log(inputArr);
});
```

```html
<form id="form-test">
  <input type="number" id="form-val" value="1">
  <button type="button" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: that is good to know.  As I am still learning, I have tendency to overthink my solutions.  Thank you!

Comment: @JoeBates You're welcome. Please "up vote" all answers that were helpful.

Comment: looks like I need 15 points in order for my upvote to display!  I will work on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `indexOf`. It will check if the value exist in the array.If not then it will add the element

```js
let inputArr = [];

document.getElementById("submit-btn").onclick = function submitFormVal(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let inputVal = document.getElementById("form-val").value;

  if (inputArr.indexOf(inputVal) === -1) {
    inputArr.push(inputVal)
  }
  console.log(inputArr);
};
```

```html
<form id="form-test">
  <input type="number" id="form-val" value="1">
  <button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: I don't see where the OP mentioned checking to see if the value was already in the array is a requirement.